# How to use dynamic user-agent header using PHP Curl or Guzzle Client

Tags: php, user-agent, guzzle, php-curl

I am new to PHP and trying to call a REST Service. I could do that using either Curl or Guzzle Client in PHP. Later I am calling this from Mozilla and Chrome Browser.

The problem is Guzzle and Curl are not forwarding the actual User-Agent header as Request Header to the backend services.

The default Guzzle `User-Agent header is Guzzle/ver curl/ver PHP/ver`

I know we can add custom/hardcoded headers in both Curl and Guzzle. But I dont want to hardcode.

```
<?php 
require './vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://sample.com');
$data = json_decode($res->getBody(), true); 
//echo  $res->getBody()  
?> 

<html>
<body>
    <p>Body  is  <?php echo  $res->getBody() ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I call the PHP service from either Chrome/Mozilla/Mobile/Safari, I want the respective `user-agent` headers to be sent as request headers to backend services.

If there a way to do this in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a build-in array which stores data from request -`$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

You can then set the `user-agent` guzzle uses with the [`headers`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers) option.

```
$client->request('GET', '/get', [
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for.
BTW the users will be passing dynamic Headers and Query Parameters in the Browser/Rest Client. Will Guzzle append those value and then hit the backend service?

As per my questions, lets say user sends an query parameter localhost/phpUI?key=123

Will this key be appended in http://sample.com?key=123 inside Guzzle client?

Comment: @JohnSeen No, the Guzzle request is entierly separate from the clients request. You can use [the query option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#query) to specify get parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Somrlik, for the advice. But I was not able to use custom queryparameter. The users will pass `?apikey=xxx` and header `x-api-key` using Rest Client. How do I use $_SERVER values for this? Should I give `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_KEY']` for header. How can I give queryparam in same way?

Answer (score 2):

For GuzzleHttp\Client:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    ]
]);
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://sample.com');
```

or

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://sample.com', [
    'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    ]
]);
```

For php cUrl:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://sample.com',
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Hope this helps for someone